# percentage of memory used used by a process

Tags: performance, unix, command-line

percentage of memory used used by a process.

normally prstat -J will give the memory of process image and RSS(resident set size) etc.
how do i knowlist of processes with  percentage of memory is used by a each process.

i am working on solaris unix.
addintionally ,what are the regular commands that you use for monitoring processes,performences of processes that might be very useful to all!

Answer (score 0):

The `top` command will give you several memory-consumption numbers. `htop` is much nicer, and will give you percentages, but it isn't installed by default on most systems.

Comment: top command will not give the percentage of memory usage and that is what my question is

Comment: That's why I also suggested `htop`.

Answer (score 0):

run

`top` and then `Shift+O` this will bring you to the options, press `n`  (this maybe different on your machine) for memory and then hit enter

Example of memory sort.

```
 top - 08:17:29 up 3 days,  8:54,  6 users,  load average: 13.98, 14.01, 11.60
Tasks: 654 total,   2 running, 652 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 14.7%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 59.5%id, 23.5%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.8%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65851896k total, 49049196k used, 16802700k free,  1074664k buffers
Swap: 50331640k total,        0k used, 50331640k free, 32776940k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                         
21635 oracle    15   0 6750m 636m  51m S  1.6  1.0  62:34.53 oracle                                                                                          
21623 oracle    15   0 6686m 572m  53m S  1.1  0.9  61:16.95 oracle                                                                                          
21633 oracle    16   0 6566m 445m 235m S  3.7  0.7  30:22.60 oracle                                                                                          
21615 oracle    16   0 6550m 428m 220m S  3.7  0.7  29:36.74 oracle                                                                                          
16349 oracle    RT   0  431m 284m  41m S  0.5  0.4   2:41.08 ocssd.bin                                                                                       
17891 root      RT   0  139m 118m  40m S  0.5  0.2  41:08.19 osysmond                                                                                        
18154 root      RT   0  182m  98m  43m S  0.0  0.2  10:02.40 ologgerd                                                                                        
12211 root      15   0 1432m  84m  14m S  0.0  0.1  17:57.80 java
```

Another method on Solaris is to do the following

```
prstat -s size 1 1
```

Example prstat output

```
www004:/# prstat -s size 1 1
   PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP       
   420 nobody    139M   60M sleep   29   10   1:46:56 0.1% webservd/76
   603 nobody    135M   59M sleep   29   10   5:33:18 0.1% webservd/96
   339 root      134M   70M sleep   59    0   0:35:38 0.0% java/24
   435 iplanet   132M   55M sleep   29   10   1:10:39 0.1% webservd/76
   573 nobody    131M   53M sleep   29   10   0:24:32 0.0% webservd/76
   588 nobody    130M   53M sleep   29   10   2:40:55 0.1% webservd/86
   454 nobody    128M   51M sleep   29   10   0:09:01 0.0% webservd/76
   489 iplanet   126M   49M sleep   29   10   0:00:13 0.0% webservd/74
   405 root      119M   45M sleep   29   10   0:00:13 0.0% webservd/31
   717 root       54M   46M sleep   59    0   2:31:27 0.2% agent/7
```

Keep in mind this is sorted by Size not RSS, if you need it by RSS use the `rss` key

```
www004:/# prstat -s rss 1 1
   PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP       
   339 root      134M   70M sleep   59    0   0:35:39 0.1% java/24
   420 nobody    139M   60M sleep   29   10   1:46:57 0.4% webservd/76
   603 nobody    135M   59M sleep   29   10   5:33:19 0.5% webservd/96
   435 iplanet   132M   55M sleep   29   10   1:10:39 0.0% webservd/76
   573 nobody    131M   53M sleep   29   10   0:24:32 0.0% webservd/76
   588 nobody    130M   53M sleep   29   10   2:40:55 0.0% webservd/86
   454 nobody    128M   51M sleep   29   10   0:09:01 0.0% webservd/76
   489 iplanet   126M   49M sleep   29   10   0:00:13 0.0% webservd/74
```

Comment: this is not working on my machine.is thr any other way i can do this?

Comment: What version of solaris is this running on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if ps is standardized but at least on linux, ps -o %mem gives the percentage of memory used (you would obviously want to add some other columns as well)